# Youtube data api works in vscode but not in pyinstaller .exe

Tags: python, youtube-api, pyinstaller, youtube-data-api

I am currently working on a python script to access the youtube data api v3. The script works just fine inside vscode (Windows 11 pro, Python 3.10.6 x64). This test script is not the one i am working on but it is enough to reproduce the error.

```
from urllib import request, response
from googleapiclient import discovery

youtube = discovery.build("youtube", "v3", developerKey="my api key")

request = youtube.search().list(
    part="snippet",
    type="channel",
    q="mrbeast",
    maxResults=1
    )

response = request.execute()

print(response["items"][0]["snippet"]["title"])
```

I converted the script to an .exe via

```
PS C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Python projects> pyinstaller --onefile api_test.py
```

and it worked just fine. However, when i execute it within PS, i get this strange error message:

```
PS C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Python projects\dist> ./api_test.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "api_test.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "googleapiclient\_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
  File "googleapiclient\discovery.py", line 287, in build
  File "googleapiclient\discovery.py", line 404, in _retrieve_discovery_doc
googleapiclient.errors.UnknownApiNameOrVersion: name: youtube  version: v3
[20192] Failed to execute script 'api_test' due to unhandled exception!
```

How can this happen and has anyone an idea how to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are a number of questions already with this error message  Did none of them help you?  [python + UnknownApiNameOrVersion](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+UnknownApiNameOrVersion)    Not to mention 31 issues on the [issue forum](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/search?q=UnknownApiNameOrVersion&type=issues)

Answer (score 1):

Adding `static_discovery=False` to `discovery.build()` solved the problem for me, although it should not have worked in the source code according to [this document](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/main/UPGRADING.md#for-users-of-private-apis).